# what could cause java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException in Netty?

Tags: java, netty

I have a Netty based client configured with multiple ChannelHandlers. First there is a FrameDecoder ( meant to decode frames arriving on the wire ) and then there is a ChannelHandler that is supposed to do certain other things ( but not message processing ).

I am seeing a lot of  `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` on the second handler - is this because of something not working correctly between the FrameDecoder and the second handler ?  I often return ChannelBuffers.EMPTY_BUFFER from the first decoder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you are creating one instance of the FrameDecoder per channel (i.e. per pipeline created) and not sharing a single instance of it ?

Having done that, can you post the code for your pipeline factory ?